# Python Plotly Dash: Customizing loading icon

Tags: python, plotly-dash

From Plotly Dash documentation, I understood that we can change between two types of icon, `default` and `circle` via `type` variable, when an app wrapped by `dcc.Loading` is loading:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H3("Edit text input to see loading state"),
        dcc.Input(id="input-1", value='Input triggers local spinner'),
        dcc.Loading(id="loading-1", children=[html.Div(id="loading-output-1")], type="default"),
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Input(id="input-2", value='Input triggers nested spinner'),
                dcc.Loading(
                    id="loading-2",
                    children=[html.Div([html.Div(id="loading-output-2")])],

                    ### Change preferred type of loading icon here
                    type="circle",
                )
            ]),
    ],)
```

However, I am looking for a way to customize my own loading icon, possibly with a gif image. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are five types by default, but to create your own loading icons, you need to create your own CSS, html, and js, right? Please refer to [this page](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-loading-states/5687/4).